# How to enable Swagger on remote dev environment in ASP.NET Core Web API app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, swagger

When developing on my local machine I am working under `Development` environment. The code that enables swagger is thus available with this condition:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

I want to enable swagger on remote hosted server that is also used as development for other members of the team. However I don't want to use other local development environment variables localted in `appsettings.Development.json` such as db connection string.

What is the best way to set this up? How should I differentiate between local and remote dev environment so that I can enable swagger on both but keep database connection string separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have access to the Remote Server and Admin privileges (Assuming it is Windows) you need to set a system environment variable:

- Variable Name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
- Variable Value: Development

**To do** this Search Environment Variables. This will open a System Properties window and under the Advanced Tab click on Environment Variables...

Create a new **System** Environment Variable with the above details

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfpjb.png)

If you don't have access to the remote server try and get in contact with someone who does.

Hope this helps.

**Alternatively** you can create a custom environment variable as the value and add it into your C# project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0

This should avoid the appsettings.Development.json file being picked-up on build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have access to the remote server so I can add env variable. Ideally, I'd like remote dev environment to take all settings from local dev environment appsettings and then override just a few of them. Do you know is this possible?

Comment: Your best bet would be to either change your local or development environment settings to a custom environment and copy the settings. You want over.

I.E:
Lets say you named your remote server environment **DevServer**

You change the Environment variable value on the remote server to DevServer.
You create a new file appsettings.DevServer.json and copy the settings you want and leave out the ones you don't.
Your Swagger if statement should now look like:
`if (app.Environment.IsDevelopement() || app.IsEnvironment("DevServer") {
// Swagger Calls
}`

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe removing the if statement will do this.

Comment: Yes but I don't want swagger on production.